# Get total amount invoiced by salesperson code by customer

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

How do I get a total `Amount` invoiced by `Salesperson Code` by `Customer` given the following query?

```
SELECT  l.[Customer No_], c.[Name], l.[Amount], c.[Salesperson Code], l.[Posting Date]
FROM    [Service Invoice Line] l join [Customer] c on 
        l.[Customer No_] = c.[No_]
Where   l.[Posting date] >= '10-01-2012'
        and c.[Salesperson Code] > ''
Group by l.[Customer No_],c.[Name],c.[Salesperson Code],l.[Amount],l.[Posting Date]
Order by l.[Customer No_]
```

Comment: You've tagged your question correctly with aggregate functions. Try to apply one of them. Read about `GROUP BY`, at least one column in your statement is too much. This is no "we do your work for you" site, show some effort.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to do my work.  I'm relatively new to SQL and am trying to learn. I've looked through both of my reference books, both fundamentals and advanced, and have not been able to discern the problem.  Searched the internet for hours...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no native english speaker, so bear with me, I'm not quite sure, what

> invoiced by Salesperson Code by Customer

means (considering your column names), so I simplified your example query (as to how I understand it)

Since you want to have the sum of amount, don't group by on it, remove it from the group by clause. Apply the sum() function to the amount column.

With a group by clause you're basically collapsing groups of rows. But your database needs to know, which of the rows to displayed for the collapsed group. So for each column you have in your select clause, you either apply an aggregate function on it, or you specify the column in the group by clause. An example of your requirement would be

```
SELECT  l.[Customer No_], c.[Name], c.[Salesperson Code], SUM(l.[Amount])
FROM    [Service Invoice Line] l join [Customer] c on 
        l.[Customer No_] = c.[No_]
Where   l.[Posting date] >= '10-01-2012'
        and c.[Salesperson Code] > ''
Group by l.[Customer No_], c.[Name], c.[Salesperson Code]
```

This will give you for each customer_no / customer_name (assuming a customer_no can not have multiple customer_names) and each salesperson_code (assuming each customer has 1 or more salesperson) the sum of the amount.

Is this what you want?

Comment: This was perfect and the explanation was spot on.  Thanks for your help.  I hope to contribute to the site at some point in the future.  Very much appreciated.